# Pandas Similar Function to COUNTIFS

Tags: python, pandas

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qn982.png)

Please see Sample Data image.  I'm trying to replicate the COUNTIFS functionality within Python / Pandas but I'm having troubles finding the correct solution.

=COUNTIFS(B:B,"BD*",A:A,A2,C:C,">"&C2)

B is the Type column, A is the Reference column, and C is the Doc Condition column.  So the count is only greater than zero if the Type is 'BD', the Reference Matches the current row's Reference, and the Doc Condition is greater than the current row's Doc Condition.  I hope that makes sense?

I've tried coming to a solution using GroupBy but I'm not getting any closer to my desired solution and I think I'm overcomplicating this.

Comment: What do you mean 'the reference matches the current row's reference'? I imagine I understand the current row and so the 'current row's reference', but what is the other reference that is compared to this? same question for your doc condition comparison. It looks like from the formula we are always comparing against the first row, is that right?

Comment: Not sure I'll explain this the best:  A2 and C2 are dynamic references.  If you're on row 20 then they'll be A20 and C20.  Simply stated the formula is asking: How many items have a BD Doc Type, the same Reference as mine, and a Doc Condition greater than mine.  'Mine' being the individual row's data.  So if it's Row 5 it's A5 & C5.  Row 99 it's A99 & C99.  Hope that makes sense?  The solution below I think tackles my problem but after additional consideration I think I'm just approaching the problem in the wrong way. Going back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include your input data as text. Screenshots are really hard to work with.

You can use numpy broadcasting. However, this will have an `n^2` computational complexity since you are comparing every row against every other row:

```py
reference, type_, doc_condition = df.to_numpy().T
match = (
    (type_[:, None] == "BD")
    & (reference[:, None] == reference)
    & (doc_condition[:, None] < doc_condition)
)
df["COUNTIFS"] = match.sum(axis=1)
```

Within the snippet above, you can read `reference[:, None]` as "the Reference value of the current row; `reference` as "the Reference values of all rows". This is what enables the comparison between the current row and all other rows (including itself) by numpy.

Comment: Sorry about the format.  I was trying to figure out how to get a table but I'm not familiar with the SO tools and I was afraid that trying to fumble through it I'd end up distracting from the problem at hand.

I don't 100% follow your solution but I'm going to try and implement it into my project.  I'll respond back with my results.  Thank you very much for the response!

Comment: Also - you referenced the computational complexity.  Maybe there's a more elegant solution?  I have a *significant* amount of data that I'm trying to identify only the latest relevant entries.  So basically once my calculation comes back I need to throw out any rows with a non-zero result since they're not the latest relevant entry for a particular Reference Document.  When the dataset was much smaller Excel could handle this logic easily but now that it's grown to over a million rows it takes significantly longer which is why I've moved into Python / Pandas.

Comment: I was able to work through your solution and get it implemented into my project.  Unfortunately I think there's too much data for how I'm trying to implement this as it's giving me a Memory error.  My planned solution is just too ugly / "brute force" so I need to go back to the drawing board.


I really appreciate your suggestion!!  I learned something new.